# Castle Windsor Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentRegistrationException

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I am tring to register a fake Authentication Service for debuging using:

```
container.Register(Component
    .For<Services.IFormsAuthenticationService>()
    .ImplementedBy<Services.DebugAuthenticationService>());
```

where Services.DebugAuthenticationService implementes 
Services.IFormsAuthenticationService

but I get this error:

Unit Test Adapter threw exception: Type is not resolved for member 'Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentRegistrationException,Castle.MicroKernel, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc'..

Comment: please post the full exception stack trace

Comment: I think I get this becuase the interface IFormsAuthenticationService is already registered with another Implementation. 
Is there a way to unregister it? or change it?

Comment: please post the full exception stack trace

Comment: actually im getting the same error (in ver 3.3.0) on unit tests on the build server. there is no other stack trace info, and locally the tests succeed. hmmmm

Answer (score 0):

Component for what? Implemented by what? You're missing the types.

Here you can find an example of correctly using `Component.For ... ImplementedBy`:

[Implementing UnitOfWork with Castle.Windsor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473713/implementing-unitofwork-with-castle-windsor)